# problems with databinding with angularjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

Hy folks, I got a problem with databinding. I tried since ages to figure out why my few has no access to my global.user provided by a service. 
Could somebody figure out whats happening. Thank in advance. best regards Thomas

profile.html

```
<section data-ng-controller="MyprofileController">
<h1>{{global.current_User()}}</h1>
</section>
```

myprofile.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean.system').controller('MyprofileController', ['$scope', 'Global',         function ($scope, Global) {
$scope.global = Global;
$scope.test = 'testcase';}]);
```

service

```
'use strict';

//Global service for global variables
angular.module('mean.system').factory('Global', [
function() {
    var current_user = window.user;
    return {
        current_User: function() {
            return current_user;
        },
        isloggedIn: function() {
            return !!current_user;
        }
    };
}
```

]);

thanks a lot for your help.

Just found out that firefox does print an error message!

```
 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MyprofileController' is not a function, got undefined
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/ng/areq?
 p0=MyprofileController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
 minErr/<@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:78
 assertArg@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:1363
 assertArgFn@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:1374
 @http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6774
 nodeLinkFn/<@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6186
 forEach@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:310
 nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6173
 compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:5637
 publicLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:5542
 ngViewFillContentFactory/<.link@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular-route/angular-     
 route.js:915
 nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6228
 compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:5637
 publicLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:5542
 boundTranscludeFn@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:5656
 controllersBoundTransclude@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6248
 update@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js:865
 Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:12245
 updateRoute/<@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js:556
 qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http:
 //localhost:3000/lib/angular/angu     lar.js:10949
 qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http:
 //localhost:3000/lib/angular/angu     lar.js:10949
 qFactory/ref/<.then/<@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:11035
 Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:11961
 Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:11787
 Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:12067
 @http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:9202
 createEventHandler/eventHandler/<@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:2613
 forEach@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:310
 createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:2612

 <section class="ng-scope" data-ng-view="">
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work, and it does in a Fiddle I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/BernhardW/mLQWs/

```
window.user = 'John Doe';

angular.module('mean.system', []);

angular.module('mean.system').controller('MyprofileController', function ($scope, Global) {
    $scope.global = Global;
    $scope.test = 'testcase';
});

angular.module('mean.system').factory('Global', function() {
    var current_user = window.user;

    return {
        current_User: function() {
            return current_user;
        },
        isloggedIn: function() {
            return !!current_user;
        }
    };
});
```

Are there any errors showing?

Comment: No thats the thing I don't get any errors! just dosent work. I startet with mean.io as template.

Comment: You could recreate a simplified example (with only the necessary code) either on http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://plnkr.co/ and I will have a look. The error seems to be outside of the code posted, because when I copy & paste your code above, everything works.

Comment: I just found out that firefox does print a error message! Does this help?

Comment: You probably got your module definition wrong. It should be `angular.module('mean.system', []);`. Because you receive such an error message when you attach your controller to a module that doesn't exist.

Comment: angular.module('mean', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute','ui.bootstrap', 'ui.route', 'mean.system']);
angular.module('mean.system', []); This seems to be exactly what I did! I just don't see whats going wrong here!

Comment: It seems that the myprofile.js file in foot.jade is not loading. I don't understand why thou! Thanks again for all your help so far.

Comment: If you can and want to upload the your files somewhere, we could have a look.